# Why I can not find lowest mean absolute error using Random Forest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, kaggle

I am doing Kaggle competition with the following dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-data-for-ml-course/download/train.csv

According to the theory, by increasing number of estimators in Random Forest model the mean absolute error would drop only until some number (sweet spot) and further increase would cause overfitting. By plotting number of estimators and mean absolute errors we should get this red graph, were lowest point marks the best number of estimators.
[image]

I try to find best number of estimators with following code, but data plot shows that MAE is constantly decreasing. What do I do wrong?

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
y = train_data['SalePrice']
#for simplicity dropping all columns with missing values and non-numerical values
X = train_data.drop('SalePrice', axis=1).dropna(axis=1).select_dtypes(['number'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
mae_list = []
for n_estimators in range(10, 800, 10):
    rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators, random_state=0, n_jobs=8)
    rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = rf_model.predict(X_test)
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)
    mae_list.append({'n_est': n_estimators, 'mae': mae})

#plotting the results
plt.plot([item['n_est'] for item in mae_list], [item['mae'] for item in mae_list])
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not necessarily doing something wrong.

Looking more closely to the theoretical curves you show, you'll notice that the horizontal axis does not contain the slightest indication of the actual number of trees/iterations where such a minimum should happen. And this is a rather general feature of such theoretical predictions - they tell you something is expected, but nothing about where exactly (or even roughly) you should expect it.

Keeping this in mind, the only thing I can conclude from your second plot is that, in the specific range of ~ 800 trees you have tried, you are actually still in the "left" of the expected minimum.

Again, there is no theoretical prediction of how many trees (800 or 8,000 or...) you should add before reaching that minimum.

To bring some empirical corroboration into the discussion: in my own first Kaggle competition, we kept adding trees until we reached a number of ~ **24,000**, before our validation error started diverging (we were using GBM and not RF, but the rationale is identical).

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb of possible range where such minimum could exist knowing the number of data samples?

Comment: @wilkas None that I have ever head of (and I highly doubt that  such a rule exists).

Comment: So basically way to find this point would be to first take as big range as possible with low resolution (large step) considering reasonable computing time and then gradually increase resolution and decrease the range around the curve bottom?

Comment: @wilkas It is certainly a way, but other concerns enter into the picture if you are after solving a *practical* problem (resources, computing time, only marginal improvements above a number of trees etc). If you are after it for *theoretical* reasons (i.e. to explore/demonstrate the existence of such a minimum), sure...

Comment: Thanks, this explains why I did not find the sweet spot. Could you give any pointers for practical best estimator count search to Google in order to avoid repeating same post by changing only "why" to "how to"? :)

Comment: @wilkas as I said, I highly doubt that you'll find anything practical (we do handle the tree number as a hyperparameter, using grid searches to tune it). In case you decide to open a new question, I strongly suggest to post it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (arguably it would be off-topic here at SO). And if the answer resolved your question, kindly accept it - thanks.