# Why does my neural network never overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, deep-residual-networks

I am training a deep residual network with 10 hidden layers with game data.

Does anyone have an idea why I don't get any overfitting here?
Training and test loss still decreasing after 100 epochs of training.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17L45.jpg

Comment: maybe because there is not much variation between training and validation data?

Comment: It should be. It is shuffled and randomly split into training and validation data. I tried 80/20 and 50/50. And the inputs are game states, outputs are win probabilities. Generated through self-play. Action space is huge. So the data should all be different. Network not complex enough? I use Batchnorms, could this prevent overfitting somehow?

Comment: Maybe you are in the under-fitting regime and need to increase model complexity. It looks like your training loss has plateaued out at 0.2

Comment: There is no guarantee that a model should start overfitting after a given number of epochs; see [Why I can not find lowest mean absolute error using Random Forest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931289/why-i-can-not-find-lowest-mean-absolute-error-using-random-forest/53931911#53931911) (it's about RF, but the rationale is the same).

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of advice:

1. for deep learning is recommended to do even 90/10 or 95/5 splitting (Andrew Ng)
2. this small difference between curves means that your `learning_rate` is not tuned; try to increase it (and, probably, number of `epochs` if you will implement some kind of 'smart' lr-reduce)
3. it is also reasonable for DNN to try to overfit with the small amount of data (10-100 rows) and an enormous number of iterations
4. check for data leakage in the set: weights analysis inside each layer may help you in this

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments.
Unfortunately I was still not able to get any overfitting.
I tried a more complex (deeper and wider) and an less complex net, I tried only a very small dataset, I tried learning rates for Adam down to 0.0000000001, and I tried thousands of learning epochs.
It's weired... could my batchnorm layers be the reason? I don't use any dropout or L2-regularization.

Comment: So, switch it off. Try to overfit small dataset without any BM.

Comment: I completely removed all BM layers just for testing purposes. My model then wasn't learning much anymore.

Comment: So, if you can not even overfit a small set it can be that your NN has a wrong architecture. Try to go from the simplest one increasing complexity one step at the time.

Also, preferably go deeper, not wider.

BTW, did you use stratified split?

Comment: Do you have a source to the 90/10 theory?